# GDAL Warp Using QGIS from AK_IFR to EPSG:4326 looks odd

Tags: qgis, gdal, gdalwarp

I am using QGIS for converting tiff from AK_IFR to EPSG:4326 (CRS), but in QGIS tiff looking perfect

[image]

but while exporting it looks like this

[image]

**Source Image Details:** [FAA IFR Chart](https://aeronav.faa.gov/enroute/05-19-2022/enr_akh02.zip)

**Extent**  -3738773.4199999999254942,-194349.8061717178206891
: 819446.2539994539692998,1674273.9499999999534339

**Width**   24613
**Height**  10090

**Data type**
**Byte** - Eight bit unsigned integer
**GDAL Driver Description** GTiff
**GDAL Driver Metadata**    GeoTIFF

**Dataset Description**
**Band 1**
STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
STATISTICS_MEAN=180.24847437723
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=112.31675006634
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
**Band 2**
STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
STATISTICS_MEAN=180.23919541579
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=111.97269231222
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
**Band 3**
STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
STATISTICS_MEAN=180.3117834084
STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
STATISTICS_STDDEV=111.73696572256
STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100

**More information**
Dimensions  X: 24613 Y: 10090 Bands: 3
Origin  -3.73877e+06,1.67427e+06
Pixel Size  185.1956150814388309,-185.1956150814388309

**Coordinate Reference System (CRS)**
Name:   AK_IFR
Units:  meters
Method: Lambert Conformal Conic
Celestial body  Earth
Reference:  Static (relies on a datum which is plate-fixed)

[image]

Comment: How are you exporting it? Your screenshot is from windows photo viewer, does it look ok if you drag and drop it to QGIS?

Comment: Please run gdalinfo for the source image and add the report to your question.

Comment: @user30184 I have added source image detail please have a look again, thank you

Comment: @BERA its not looking ok in QGIS too https://ibb.co/4TrZ0D9

Comment: The source CRS does not seem to be EPSG:4326.

Comment: @user30184 yes source CRS is AK_IFR, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The map goes over the dateline: West_Bounding_Coordinate: 148.175845, East_Bounding_Coordinate: -138.964596. QGIS shows EPSG:4326 map in range from -180 to 180 degrees and therefore the map gets splitted in two halves. The result is correct even it does look odd.

This command prevents the split but eastern side will have longitudes which are larger than 180.

```
gdalwarp -t_srs epsg:4326 ENR_AKH02.tif enr_4326_180.tif --config CENTER_LONG 180
Creating output file that is 26203P x 9758L.
Processing ENR_AKH02.tif [1/1] : 0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

[image]